# What are historical examples of (alleged) miracles that were attested to by two or more (self-proclaimed) eyewitnesses?

Tags: church-history, miracles, witness

The resurrection of Jesus is the most famous and obvious one, with the apostles being the eyewitnesses. Latter-day Saints would probably put forth the [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Witnesses) & [8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Witnesses) witnesses to the miraculous golden plates. Are there any other notable examples in the history of the Church?

**Note**: Why two or more witnesses? Because *in the mouth of two or three witnesses shall every matter be established* (2 Cor 13:1).

Comment: The Miracle of the Sun at Fatima, Portugal in 1917 comes to mind. In addition, there are many Marian apparitions with 2+ self-proclaimed eyewitnesses.

Comment: When you say **alleged** miracles, do you mean false miracles or or simply miracles that have been reported as such?

Comment: @KenGraham - First, notice that I put the word (alleged) inside parentheses to denote that it is optional, but I'm just using it with the intended meaning of "claimed to be so without substantial evidence".

Comment: Understood, just looking for clarity.

Comment: I'll post an answer, but what do you mean by historical (happened before year 2000, something else)?

Comment: @depperm - I just meant to say that we have historical evidence that they took place, by the recorded testimonies of two or more (self-proclaimed) witnesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What are historical examples of (alleged) miracles that were attested to by two or more self-proclaimed eyewitnesses?**

Would an alleged miracle witnessed by a conservative number of 30,000 witnesses fit the bill?

If so, then the **Miracle of the Sun** of October 31, 1917, seems to fit in here.

> The [**Miracle of the Sun**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_Sun), also known as the ***Miracle of Fátima***, is a series of events reported to have occurred miraculously on 13 October 1917, attended by a large crowd who had gathered in Fátima, Portugal, in response to a prophecy made by three shepherd children, Lúcia Santos and Francisco and Jacinta Marto. The prophecy was that the Virgin Mary (referred to as Our Lady of Fátima), would appear and perform miracles on that date. Newspapers published testimony from witnesses who said that they had seen extraordinary solar activity, such as the **Sun appearing to "dance" or zig-zag in the sky, careen towards the Earth, or emit multicolored light and radiant colors. According to these reports, the event lasted approximately ten minutes.**
>
> The local bishop opened a canonical investigation of the event in November 1917, to review witness accounts and assess whether the alleged private revelations from Mary were compatible with Catholic theology. The local priest conducting the investigation was particularly convinced by the concurring testimony of extraordinary solar phenomena from secular reporters, government officials, and other skeptics in attendance. Bishop José da Silva declared the miracle "worthy of belief" on 13 October 1930, permitting "officially the cult of Our Lady of Fatima" within the Catholic Church.
>
> At a gathering on 13 October 1951 at Fátima, the papal legate, Cardinal Federico Tedeschini, told the million people attending that on 30 October, 31 October, 1 November, and 8 November 1950, **Pope Pius XII himself witnessed the miracle of the Sun from the Vatican gardens**. The early and enduring interest in the miracle and related prophecies has had a significant impact on the devotional practices of many Catholics.
>
> There has been much analysis of the event from critical sociological and scientific perspectives. According to critics, the eyewitness testimony was actually a collection of inconsistent and contradictory accounts. Proposed alternative explanations include witnesses being deceived by their senses due to prolonged staring at the Sun and then seeing something unusual as expected.
>
> **The event**
>
> **Estimates of the number of people present range from 30,000 and 40,000, by Avelino de Almeida writing for the Portuguese newspaper O Século, to 100,000**, estimated by lawyer Dr. José Almeida Garrett, the son of a professor of natural sciences at the University of Coimbra.
>
> Various claims have been made as to what actually happened during the event. According to many witnesses, after a period of rain, the dark clouds broke and the Sun appeared as an opaque, spinning disc in the sky. It was said to be significantly duller than normal, and to cast multicolored lights across the landscape, the people, and the surrounding clouds. The Sun was then reported to have careened towards the Earth before zig-zagging back to its normal position.[18][19] Witnesses reported that their previously wet clothes became "suddenly and completely dry, as well as the wet and muddy ground that had been previously soaked because of the rain that had been falling". Not all witnesses reported seeing the Sun "dance". Some people only saw the radiant colors, and others, including some believers, saw nothing at all. According to skeptic Brian Dunning, "An old black and white photograph of the actual sun miracle event shows a lot of dark rain clouds behind some trees and the sun poking through. There is certainly nothing in the photograph that looks unusual, but of course a photograph is static. Whatever the crowd saw was not interesting enough to be noticeable in a photograph".
>
> The three children (Lúcia dos Santos and her cousins Jacinta and Francisco Marto) who originally claimed to have seen Our Lady of Fátima also reported seeing a panorama of visions, including those of Jesus, Our Lady of Sorrows, Our Lady of Mount Carmel, and of Saint Joseph blessing the people. In the fourth edition of her memoirs, written in 1941, Lúcia said that on the occasion of their third visit to the Cova da Iria, on 13 July 1917, she asked the Lady to tell them who she was, and to perform a miracle so that everyone would believe. The Lady told her that they should continue to come to the Cova each month until October, when the requested miracle would occur.
>
> [image: Page from Ilustração Portuguesa, 29 October 1917, showing the people looking at the Sun during the Fátima apparitions attributed to the Virgin Mary]
>
> Page from Ilustração Portuguesa, 29 October 1917, showing the people looking at the Sun during the Fátima apparitions attributed to the Virgin Mary
>
> [image: The crowd at Cova da Iria looking towards the Sun on 13 October 1917]
>
> The crowd at Cova da Iria looking towards the Sun on 13 October 1917
>
> [image: Part of the crowd looking at the Sun during the event]
>
> Part of the crowd looking at the Sun during the event

This miracle was witnessed by people several kilometres away.

> The **miracle of the sun** continues to defy experts to this day. No eclipse or other astronomical event was observed on October 13, 1917. The miracle could not have been mass hysteria, because people observed the event miles away. It could not have been religious fervor, because many witnesses were indifferent or even hostile to the Faith!
>
> [image: THE DAY THE SUN DANCED: FATIMA 1917]
>
> [The Day the Sun Danced: Fatima1917](https://www.churchmilitant.com/news/article/the-day-the-sun-danced-fatima-1917)

[Pope Pius XII witnessed the Fatima “miracle of the sun” while walking in the Vatican gardens](https://aleteia.org/2019/05/13/pope-pius-xii-witnessed-the-fatima-miracle-of-the-sun-while-walking-in-the-vatican-gardens/) Pius XII died on October 9, 1958, and was buried a few days later — on October 13, 1958, the anniversary of the “miracle of the sun” at Fatima.

Comment: Very interesting reading about this event. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Many Latter-day Saints experienced many miracles at the Kirtland Temple.

William Draper ([account](http://www.boap.org/LDS/Early-Saints/WDraper.html)):

> And there in the [Kirtland] temple on the Day of Pentecost of the 6th day of April 1836 there was such a time of the outpouring of the spirit of the Lord that my pen is inadequate to write it in full or my tongue to express it. But I will here say that the spirit was poured out and came like a mighty rushing wind and filled the house, **that many that were present spoke in tongues and had visions and saw angels and prophesied**, and had a general time of rejoicing such as had not been known in this generation.

Milo Anders ([account](http://miloandrus.org/the_autobiograp/)):

> The summer of 1835, I traveled in the state of New York with Nathan Baldwin, baptized several, and the following winter went to school in Kirtland, and in the spring of 1836, I was in Kirtland at the dedication of the temple and the endowment of the elders that the Lord had promised as a reward for their offerings. The blessings of the Lord were poured out abundantly. There is one thing that I would here relate, that was a great joy to me, and that was when the Holy Ghost was poured out on the elders, **I saw fire descend and rest on the heads of the elders, and they spoke with tongues, and prophesied**.

Joseph Smith, History of the Church, Vol 2([account](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/47192/47192-h/47192-h.htm))

> ...called upon the congregation to speak, and not to fear to prophesy good concerning the Saints, for if you prophesy the falling of these hills and the rising of the valleys, the downfall of the enemies of Zion and the rising of the kingdom of God, it shall come to pass. Do not quench the Spirit, for the first one that opens his mouth shall receive the Spirit of prophecy.

> Brother George A. Smith arose and began to prophesy, when a noise was heard like the sound of a rushing mighty wind, which filled the Temple, and all the congregation simultaneously arose, **being moved upon by an invisible power; many began to speak in tongues and prophesy; others saw glorious visions; and I beheld the Temple was filled with angels**, which fact I declared to the congregation. The people of the neighborhood came running together (hearing an unusual sound within, and seeing a bright light like a pillar of fire resting upon the Temple), and were astonished at what was taking place

> ...The number of official members present on this occasion was four hundred and sixteen

Prescindia Huntington (source is a [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6358596-the-women-of-mormondom)-unread, may read differently, taken from this [site](http://www.moroni10.com/mormon_history/kirtland-temple-miracles.html))

> In Kirtland we enjoyed many very great blessings, and **often saw the power of God manifested. On one occasion I saw angels clothed in white walking upon the temple.** It was during one of our monthly fast meetings, when the saints were in the temple worshiping. **A little girl came to my door and in wonder called me out, exclaiming, 'The meeting is on the top of the meetinghouse!' I went to the door, and there I saw on the temple angels clothed in white covering the roof from end to end**. They seemed to be walking to and fro; they appeared and disappeared. The third time they appeared and disappeared before I realized that they were not mortal men. Each time in a moment they vanished, and their reappearance was the same. This was in broad daylight, in the afternoon. A number of the children in Kirtland saw the same.

> "When the brethren and sisters came home in the evening, they told of the power of God manifested in the temple that day, and of the **prophesying and speaking in tongues. It was also said, in the interpretation of tongues, 'That the angels were resting down upon the house.**'

> "At another fast meeting I was in the temple with my sister Zina. The whole of the congregation were on their knees, praying vocally, for such was the custom at the close of these meetings when Father Smith presided; yet there was no confusion; the voices of the congregation mingled softly together. While the congregation was thus praying, **we both heard, from one corner of the room above our heads, a choir of angels singing most beautifully. They were invisible to us, but myriads of angelic voices seemed to be united in singing some song of Zion, and their sweet harmony filled the temple of God**.

Nancy Harlacher (same source as above? taken from the same site)

> "We were also in the temple at the pentecost. In the morning Father Smith prayed for a pentecost, in opening the meeting. That day the power of God rested mightily upon the saints. **There was poured out upon us abundantly the spirit of revelation, prophesy and tongues**. The Holy Ghost filled the house; and along in the afternoon a noise was heard. It was the sound of a mighty rushing wind. But at first the congregation was startled, not knowing what it was. To many it seemed as though the roof was all in flames. Father Smith exclaimed, 'Is the house on fire?'

> "'Do you not remember your prayer this morning, Father Smith?' inquired a brother.

> "Then the patriarch, clasping his hands, exclaimed, 'The spirit of God, like a mighty rushing wind!'

> "At another time a cousin of ours came to visit us at Kirtland. She wanted to go to one of the saints' fast meetings, to hear someone sing or speak in tongues, but she said she expected to have a hearty laugh. Accordingly we went with our cousin to the meeting, during which **a Brother McCarter rose and sang a song of Zion in tongues; I arose and sang simultaneously with him the same tune and words, beginning and ending each verse in perfect unison, without varying a word**. It was just as though we had sung it together a thousand times. After we came out of meeting, our cousin observed, 'Instead of laughing, I never felt so solemn in my life.

---

This answer is already quite long, can provide another answer with more miracles from LDS perspective if wanted.

<sub>All emphasis mine</sub>

Comment: `This answer is already quite long, can provide another answer with more miracles from LDS perspective if wanted.` - I would not complain if you do :-)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator ok, so I can find lots of miracle stories, but not necessarily multiple accounts of it. Multiple people were present but either didn't keep a journal, it hasn't been published, or I don't have access to it. I'll will mention [John Tanner](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1979/03/the-john-tanner-family?lang=eng) which story has a [video](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/media/video/2010-07-0139-treasure-in-heaven-the-john-tanner-story?lang=eng) (just the first half has the miracle, though the rest pf the story is good too)

Answer (score 0):

Some brief examples follow.  All of these are God's working, not from any human being.

Be aware that simply googling many of these names will bring up critics like the Pharoah and his magicians who for selfish or unbelieving motivations desire to discredit them.  Remember, that many Pharisees accused Jesus, Himself of casting out demons by the power of demons.  Also, that they had Him crucified out of their own unbelief.

The documentary movie series by Darren Wilson, "Finger of God", "Father of Lights", "Furious Love", "Holy Ghost", [Multiple documentaries, including miracles](http://wpfilms.tv)
Sid Roth has a TV show, which frequently discusses modern day miracles.

A modern day example of this.  I personally prayed for Mark Houser before his miracle.  Briefly, he had partially inoperable, likely fatal, prostate cancer.  The oncologist, who did not believe in Christ, could not explain when the inoperable portion miraculously disappeared two days before the surgery.  He had posted a testimony of this on YouTube, but now I can't find it.  The oncologist became a believer after the miracle and follow up conversations with Mark.
It is written here.  [DuckDuckGo Search results](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=mark%20houser%20cancer%20testimony&atb=v223-1&ia=web) but most likely because so many people believe it is a lie, I can no longer find it here.  [Same search on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mark%20houser%22%20cancer%20testimony&biw=1387&bih=772&tbm=vid&ei=51E3YajmGMTqxgGYqZGoDQ&oq=%22mark%20houser%22%20cancer%20testimony&gs_l=psy-ab-video.3...50920.50920.0.52685.1.1.0.0.0.0.110.110.0j1.1.0..1..0...1.1.64.psy-ab-video..0.0.0....0.gXd5WuWpdsw) or here [youtube search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22mark%20houser%22%20cancer%20testimony) despite the fact I used to share his testimony through youtube.

John G. Lake is famous for miraculous healings.
"The healings that occurred under his ministry were documented thoroughly. ..."
Unfortunately, he was before video recording was widely available.
[John G. Lake documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_G._Lake)  Many accounts say, researchers could put disease on his skin and watch the disease die.  [Bubonic plague died in his hand.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=john%20g%20lake%20disease%20died%20in%20his%20hand&t=ffab&atb=v223-1&ia=web)

Smith Wigglesworth, was famous for miracles.

Todd White, a modern evangelist, has had many documented healings.

Bethel School of Supernatural Ministry in Redding California is known for miraculous healings.

Heidi Baker has multiple documented healings.

Kathryn Kuhlman also has documented healings.

Related note: The question as currently stated is not clear about LDS or a more general perspective.  None of the people mentioned above agree with LDS theology.

The Azusa street revival may have some on video.
[Azusa street search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=azusa%20street%20revival%20miracles&t=ffab&atb=v223-1&ia=web)

Comment: `The question as currently stated is not clear about LDS or a more general perspective.` - I don't believe it is meant to be LDS-specific. Just one answerer is giving an LDS perspective.

Comment: "Bethel School of Supernatural Ministry" - looked it up, what an interesting read that was! Failed prophecies and relentless defense of gay conversation therapy! If God is giving anybody healing powers, seems doubtful that it would be the people at this organization

Comment: you seem to have already missed my warning, "Be aware that simply googling many of these names will bring up critics like the Pharoah and his magicians who for selfish or unbelieving motivations desire to discredit them."

Comment: That seems like a catch-all way to dismiss any criticism of anybody, ever.

Comment: I think it's it's Chip Ingram, who says if he's not getting persecuted that means, he takes it as a sign he's not living his faith and /or evangelizing sufficiently.  This conversation should be moved to a chat room.

Comment: That again seems like an indiscriminate way to dismiss all disagreement. "If people disagree with me, that means I'm right!" But people disagree with everything, so... everything is right? The argument is so vague and general that it absolutely can't be useful at all.

Comment: @nickalh - can you provide concrete examples, with sources, perhaps including quotes, where **two or more** witnesses testify to have witnessed the same miracle?

Comment: The Mark Houser miracle, the John G. Lake specifically have two or more witnesses.  Most or all of these have two or more witnesses, but I'm out of time to dig for them and the quotes.  And the movie series has multiple examples, at least a couple or more video taped.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I feel like there's 2 main ways to take these witnessed miracles, in this answer and the LDS one: either these miracles are fundamentally believable, OR the argument that 'multiple witnesses to a miracle make it believable' is a much weaker argument than many might think. I'm sure I don't need to say that I'm swinging toward the latter. I wonder how you've interpreted the answers provided.

Comment: @TKoL - I believe having more witnesses increases the likelihood that a genuine phenomenon actually took place instead of just being an intentionally made-up story. That said, you still have to inspect each case individually, because you can't rule out *a priori* the possibility that people might be sincerely mistaken, because they are just misinterpreting a mundane phenomenon. You have to judge on case by case basis. But I would say that multiple consistent witnesses can potentially be very good evidence for sincerity.

Comment: I think the Miracle of the Sun is a great example where I personally wouldn't question the sincerity of the witnesses, but would insist "the best explanation for the data is not that a real miracle occurred". I think that's often the case with these things

Comment: @TKoL - would you say the apostles were sincere in their belief that Jesus resurrected?

Comment: I don't have enough information to give any reasonable speculation on that.

Comment: However, the biblical account of that particular point in time, around the resurrection immediately after Jesus death, is a point of arguable contradiction in the Bible. According to some biblical accounts, Jesus told his disciples to go to Galilee, and he met them there after resurrection. According to others, he met them in Jerusalem instead. There are of course apologetic answers to this contradiction - you can justify anything if you try hard enough! - but I do think personally that a close reading does leave one thinking it's a contradiction.

Comment: [Here's a biblical scholar giving his opinion on the reliability of the accounts of the ressurection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cDx8riNaJg) - I don't expect you or anybody to *believe* him, but I think his points are at the very least of interest even if you ultimately don't accept his point of view.